# Decision Tables Column Colouring

Tags: decision-problem

I am learning about decision tables and am confused by the colouring in the text book's mark scheme for a question I'm working on. I can not see why some of the columns have been coloured grey. Rather than adding anything to my understanding, the colouring makes me think I'm missing some important point as I can't see a commonality between the columns which have been coloured.

The Questions for which this image is the solution are: i) Complete the decision table and ii) simplify by removing redundancies.

Can anyone please explain the colouring to me?

[image]

Comment: I think you need to ask the person who produced these tables. The colouring isn't inherent to the table, right? So your question is basically "What does this person mean?"

Comment: Indeed, with the expectation that the meaning might be obvious to someone who understands the subject. I don't have access to the textbook author unfortunately.

Comment: Oh, OK -- I'd assumed that you having the mark scheme meant this was an exercise set by your professor, rather than something from a textbook. (Edited to mention that.)